# Как добавить иконку с помощью ::before?

Tags: html, css

Как добавить иконку с помощью :before?

```css
.basket::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="main-navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Студия</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Клиенты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Магазин</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="basket"><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

У меня вылетает блок before за границу li, и его просто не видно.

Comment: В примере не вылезает

Comment: нет, эту иконку нужно сделать слева от текста!

Answer (score 4):

Вот как вариант:

```css
.basket::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px 5px 0 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}

.main-navigation {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="main-navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Студия</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Клиенты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Магазин</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="basket"><a href="#">Корзина</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

По шагам

1) Берём ссылку с cdnjs.com `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css`

2) Открываем официальный сайт font-awesome: `https://fontawesome.com/`

3) Выбираем нужную иконку( я выбрал три разных )

`content: "\f007";`  `content: "\f1ea";` `content: "\f099";`

КОД НА СКРИНЕ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не забываем об обратном слеше `\` она над клавишей `Shift`

На всякий случай : [ЧаВо](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements)

Собираем всё в один html документ так :

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.login:after {
  content: "\f007";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  color: red;
}

.tps::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 400;
  content: "\f1ea";
  color: blue;
}

.twitter::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  content: "\f099";
  font-weight: 900;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">

<div class="login"></div>
<div class="tps"></div>
<div class="twitter"></div>
```

Или на крайний случай выбрать иконки -эмодзи и из вывести в псевдоэлемент вот так

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

li:first-child::before {
  content: "";
}

li:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: "";
}

li:nth-of-type(3)::before {
  content: "";
}

li:nth-of-type(4)::before {
  content: "";
}

li:nth-of-type(5)::before {
  content: "";
}

li:hover::before {
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">настройки</a></li>
  <li><a href="">важное</a></li>
  <li><a href="">знакомства</a></li>
  <li><a href="">музыка</a></li>
  <li><a href="">фото</a></li>
</ul>
```

На [toster.ru](https://qna.habr.com/q/700893) был вопрос подобный но я там реализовал по [чуть чуть по другому](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KKwxVxz?editors=1000)

Answer (score 2):

Класс .basket установите на ссылку, а li задайте position: relative; и влево на -15px отодвиньте иконку с помощью left: -15px;

```css
ul.main-navigation li{position:relative;} 

.basket::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  top:0;
  left: -15px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="main-navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Студия</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Клиенты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Магазин</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="basket">Корзина</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Но у меня работает одинаково, если и не перемещать класс .basket с li на a. От этого будет зависить кликабельная иконка будет или нет. На ваш вкус.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без `::before`, а для класса `.baket`использовать `list-style-image: url('')`